# Is there any function which second derivative is almost equivalent it major function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, derivatives

I know second derivative of $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\sinh x$, $\cosh x$ functions are equivalent themselves with different sign. So my question is there any function similar or not? Any help might be appreciated.

Comment: What are the second derivatives of $\sinh$ and $\cosh$?

Comment: @Henry , sinh and cosh

Answer (score 1):

What you are really asking is to find all solutions of the ordinary differential equations (ODE) $f^{\prime\prime} = f$ and $f^{\prime\prime} = -f$.

The general solution of the first ODE is $x\mapsto c_1 e^x + c_2 e^{-x}$. The general solution of the second ODE is $x\mapsto c_1 \sin x + c_2 \cos x$.

Comment: The general solutions of the first ODE do not include those of the second - those of the second are of the form $$c_1 e^{ix}+c_2 e^{-ix}$$ and this is where to get the $\sin$ and $\cos$ solutions from.

Comment: @JohnDoe: Ah thanks. Not sure what I was thinking there. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, only linear combinations of $\sin kx ,\cos kx $ or $\sinh kx , \cosh kx $ are solutions to the ODE:

$$ y''=\pm k^2 y$$

Comment: yes, i got my answer.thanks